# @if not rendering form options on change of other form element

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Within my view I have a select box. If a certain value is selected I want more form options to appear below using @if.

```
@model App.ViewModels.JobVM    

<div class="row">
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.Label("Job Type", new { @class = "control-label" })
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JobId, 
                               new SelectList(App.ViewModels.JobVM.GetJobs(),
                                              "Value", "Text"), 
                               "--Choose Job Type--", 
                               new { @class = "form-control"})
      </div>
 </div>
...

 @if (Model.JobId == 1)
 {
  .... more form options
 }
```

However when running if the select option that give Job ID 1; the form options don't render.

Is there a reason why the form options do not appear when the Select option changes? Or will I have to use javascript to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

It's expected behavior as view is rendered on server once before sending data to browser. However, for displaying additional inputs you can use both methods - js or partial views (even with ajax if you need) you have to use only JavaScript to show/hide other elements of form for required cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `@if` statement and `Model.JobId` executed server-side, hence `Model.JobId` value doesn't change when the dropdown selected value has changed because `change` event occurred in client-side. By handling `change` event with JS, you can use AJAX call to set the value and display additional form options which contained inside partial view:

**jQuery AJAX call**

```js
$('#JobId').change(function () {
    var jobId = $(this).val();
    if (jobId == 1) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', // or 'POST'
            url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
            data: { JobId : jobId },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#formoptions').html(result);
            },
            // other stuff
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#formoptions').empty();
    }
});
```

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult ActionName(int JobId)
{
    // do something

    return PartialView("_FormOptions", viewmodel);
}
```

If the form options are already rendered together inside view, instead of using server-side `@if` block, simply use a `<div>` placeholder and toggle its visibility like this:

```js
$('#JobId').change(function () {
    var jobId = $(this).val();
    if (jobId == 1) {
        $('#formoptions').show(); // show form options
    } else {
        $('#formoptions').hide(); // hide form options
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="formoptions">
   <!-- more form options -->
</div>
```